# Fail to install control package to Octave (installed via snap)

Tags: snap, octave

I'm facing some difficulties installing packages in octave (5.2.0 via snap). I'm running ubuntu 19.10

The problem is:

```
>> pkg install -forge control
configure: error: in `/tmp/oct-bdXz48/control-3.2.0/src':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
checking for mkoctfile... /snap/octave/22/bin/mkoctfile-5.2.0
checking for octave-config... /snap/octave/22/bin/octave-config-5.2.0
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no

pkg: error running the configure script for control.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 82 column 9
    install at line 190 column 7
    pkg at line 441 column 9
>> which make
>> which gcc
>> which g++
```

I'm `apt` kind of guy and very new to snap so I don't know if I'm looking into right direction. The `which` inside octave does not have any luck with compiler related tools, but the base installation has gcc, g++, make etc...

```
hoo2@shirka:~$ uname -a
Linux shirka 5.3.0-40-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 31 20:24:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
hoo2@shirka:~$ apt list --installed build*
Listing... Done
build-essential/eoan,now 12.8ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: You have to start with `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and then try again.

Comment: I have. Check the last 3 lines from my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the issue with Snap package, but deb-packaged version works as expected.

So I would recommend to remove Snap with `snap remove octave` and install 4.4.1 deb instead:

```
sudo apt-get install octave
```

For Octave installed from deb we usually need to install `liboctave-dev` package to compile packages from Octave Forge:

```
sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev
```

Then you can install any package from Octave Forge:

```
pkg install -forge control
```

Or install the Control package as deb-package with

```
sudo apt install octave-control
```

You have to wait for a couple of months and you will get Octave 5.2 packaged in 20.04 LTS.

---

If you really need to have 5.2 today - use FlatPak:

```
sudo apt-get install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.octave.Octave
flatpak run org.octave.Octave
```

Comment: My bad. I didn't test flatpak before posting but to be honest I have no clue of how flatpak works and I'm a little careful. I need to study it first. The reason I installed the snap was the newest version. But If the LTS will update to that then it is a sweet deal :)